# Dissolving Points using QGIS Processing?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, dissolve

Is it currently possible to create multipart features of points data based on one or more fields?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 5):

**Singleparts to multipart** accepts one field. If you want to use it for a layer with multiple fields, you can create a virtual field that combines all relevant fields

[image]

and then then run Singleparts to multipart on that

[image]